# css, lock html a tag with image inside

Tags: html, css

is there a way to lock with only CSS pictures that when someone have 800x600 resolution they will not float one under another.

now:

resolution 1600x900

pic1      pic2       pic3

resolution 800x600

pic1

pic2

pic3

wanted result:

pic1 pic2 pic3

in both resolution. With scroll if needed in smaller resolution.

Comment: A solution would to make a fixed width of div with a fixed size of images. or use % to scale the images down depending on the size of the browser.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/responsive-1200px-min.less

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use several tips

### Best solution

on the parent div, add a min-width corresponding of the sum of the size of its children. you may need an additional grand parent div with overflow:auto to show scrollbar.

### Good solution but depending on your case

specify size of floating div in %

### If none of these solution is acceptable for your case

on the children div, you can use display: table-cell. It will render as a cell table which cannot be "destroy" by minimal resolution

Comment: I don't like tables so I wouldn't really use #2 (prejudice?)

Comment: yes I agree this is not the best of three but it's a tip too ;) I update my post to reflect that

Comment: @Jan: Using the CSS `display` `table` has *nothing* to do with a HTML table. It's just about the *styling*.